# Does a Group being Finite Imply that It Is Cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples

I have been studying Abstract Algebra, and all the finite groups that we have studied so far have also been cyclic.  So, is it true that all finite groups are cyclic?
If yes, what is the theorem?  If no, please provide a counterexample.

Comment: Not by a long shot. Look up symmetric and dihedral groups.  Most finite groups are *not* cyclic or even commutative.

Comment: Smallest counterexample: $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group

Comment: The symmetric group $S_3$ is finite, of order $6$ but not is cyclic.

Comment: You may coincidentally be observed only finite groups of prime order. In this case, his statement was true, but in general is false.

Comment: I find it surprising that your teacher did not show you the group of permutations of three things as soon as groups were defined.

Comment: A group is an abstraction of the symmetries of some object. Some of the important examples are symmetries of geometric objects. For example, the group of permutations of three things that Lubin mentions in the previous comment is also the group of symmetries of an equilateral triangle; the Klein four-group mentioned by E W H Lee is the group of symmetries of a (non-square) rectangle; the ‘dihedral group of order 8” mentioned in the answer below is the group of symmetries of a square. Almost any geometric example you can think of will be acyclic.

Answer (score 4):

No. Try and find a generator for
$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$
Shouldn't take long, there's only four possibilities. Next try:

$$\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$

In general, a finite group will be cyclic if and only if it is isomorphic to some direct product of cyclic groups with relatively prime orders. For example:

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3, \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \mathbb{Z}_\mathbb{11} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$$

are cyclic. But of course, not all finite groups are Abelian (commutative) let alone cyclic.

Answer (score -1):

For abelian take klein 4 group and for non abelian  take dihedral group of order 8.